# Не отправляются письма по smtp если в поле from указана почта mail.ru

Tags: smtp, gmail, mail.ru

Да, прошу прощения, у себя на волне, в мыслях))))
работю в laravel
есть настройки для smtp

MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=somepassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

и есть функция для отправки почты:

function($mail){
    $m->from();
    $m->to(example@gmail.com);
    $m->subject('Новый ЗАПРОС');
}

собственно поле to это кому почта идет, поле from от кого, из этого поля данные подставляются автоматически в форму, когда в почтовом ящике нажимаешь "ответить".
Например если клент мне с сайта отправляет запрос, то указанный им его почтовый ящик подставится в поле from. Я получу письмо, как будто оно отправлено от этого клента.

Проблема в том, что если у клиента почта mail.ru, то письма неотправляются, любая другая почта, типа гмаил, яндекс то все работает

Comment: Что-а? Поясните подробнее. Что значит поле "from"? Это то КУДА Вы отправляете письмо или что подставляете в письме в соответствующее поле?

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил сам вопрос, надеюсь, так яснее)

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема в этом: https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/282602/